# Binding DataTemplate controls in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, binding

I have bounded DataGrid where Items are ObservableCollection of pairs {Prop1, Prop2}

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                   <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox >
                                        <TextBox.Text>
                                            <Binding Path="Prop1">
                                            </Binding>
                                        </TextBox.Text>   
                                    </TextBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How to bind TextBox Text property to Prop1? I tried as shown above but its not working (looks like data context of TextBox is set to main window).

Comment: What is the type argument of the ObservableCollection, i.e. what exactly is {Prop1, Prop2}?

Comment: @mm8, Custom class with two string properties.

Comment: Please post the definition of the class and the Items property if you want any help.

Comment: @mm8,  public class Pair
  {
   public Pair() {}

   public string Prop1 { get; set; }

   public string Prop2 { get; set; }
  }

Comment: And the view model where the Items property is defined? You should edit your question by the way.

Comment: Are you expecting to see the value of Prop1 in the TextBox or what is your exact issue?

Comment: @mm8, looks like i messed up my code using int type in data object (Prop1 and Prop2) instead of string. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: So, it works now? Or what would be the difference between binding to an int or a string in this case?

Comment: @mm8, yes, it works now. Actually i using MaskedTextBox (from Extended WPF Toolkit) instead of TextBox with hexadecimal mask "0x0000". I guess binding can't parse hex string with direct binding to int and fails on that.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to reproduce the issue in question (I assume that "it's not working" means that the value entered in the `TextBox` is not pushed to your view-model). I am not sure about the exact reasons, but it seems that in this particular scenario, if you don't explicitly set `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger`, it defaults (or at least acts like it) to `UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit`. So the solution to this problem is to explicitly set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the binding to either `UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus` or `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Prop1, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Grx70, thanks for your help. I used wrong data type on Prop1 (int instead of string), this is why binding not working properly and showing wrong values.